# Show all IDs and their values from string

Tags: javascript, string, extract

Example:

```
var string = "<h1 id='data'>Blaa</h1> <h2 id='data2'>blaa</h2>";
```

Using javascript, how can I extract the IDs and there values in a format:

data: Blaa
data2: blaa

Comment: Do you want to extract this from DOM appended elements, or from the string?

Comment: I want to extract from all tags that have the attribute 'id'

Comment: depends on the constraints of your string, but I'd start with a regex

Comment: Since this is basically xml, you could also try an xml parser...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what the context of this question is or how you intend to use the data, but here's something that I *think* does what you're asking, using vanilla JavaScript.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bLasc6n3/)

```
var string = "<h1 id='data'>Blaa</h1> <h2 id='data2'>blaa</h2>",
    div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = string;

var elements = div.getElementsByTagName('*'),
    dataValues = {},
    i = 0;
for (i; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].id) {
        dataValues[elements[i].id] = elements[i].innerHTML;
    }
}
console.log(dataValues);
```

Comment: upvoted for a non JQuery solution and using the native DOM parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse html strings with jQuery using the `parseHTML` function:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/

```
var str = "<h1 id='data'>Blaa</h1> <h2 id='data2'>blaa</h2>";
$.each( $.parseHTML(str), function( i, el ) {
    if(!el.tagName) return;
    var tagName = el.tagName.toLowerCase();
    if(tagName == 'h1' || tagName == 'h2') {
        var id = el.id;
        console.log(id + ':' + $(el).html());
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gao898r2/3/